# Android significantly slower in resizing and moving multiple canvas elements

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas

I need to build a kind of map in canvas, which must be able to hold **more than 10.000 elements** and thus has quiet big dimensions in some cases (**> 8000px width, >4000 px height**). Also I need to **pan and zoom** the map. 
After some fiddeling around with existing libraries (Paper.js) and possible other solutions (Leaflet Map) I eventually wrote an own library from scratch, because the main requirement is, that is should be **really really fast** (loading, mouseovers, ...) and none of the libraries I tried could offer **all** of the aspects.

The structure is as follows:

- I have one map object with an associated Control object, which registers events and has resize methods etc.
- A map is divided in mutliple even sized tiles (1024px x 1024px - customizable) because using the map with only one canvas at a size over 8000px width made it incredibly slow
- Each tile is associated with a canvas
- The elements (just circles) are added to one or multiple tiles (If it's on the edge) - more specifically to the tiles' canvas.
- The tiles are placed within an container div which has the dimensions of the map area (when not zoomed out)
- The container div is placed within a viewport div to enable the map being displayed as a "widget"
- Zooming scales **every** tile/canvas and the container. For sake of performance I sacrificed smooth zoom and implemented a customizable amount of zoom steps, which still feels okay.
- Panning set's the `top`and `left` style of the container.
- Events used are `window.resize`, `mousewheel`, `DOMMouseScrol`, `mousedown`, `mouseup`, `mousemove`, `touchstart`,`touchend`,`touchmove` and [Hammertime pinch](http://hammerjs.github.io/recognizer-pinch/)

This alltogether runs satisfying on Desktop Browsers, and iPhones (tested with SE, 6S) but on every **Android** device I tested it (Samsung S4, One Plus One and another 1 year old device, and android studio emulator) it runs extremly slow. Drawing of the Map is fine in speed, but **zooming and panning** is near to **impossible**.

The code is too comprehensive to post it here, so I'm asking you if there are any known problems with canvas on android, that could explain this problem, or maybe some issues with the way I built the structure that could produce issues with android. I'm really clueless here, since it works on desktop and iPhone.

Comment: Sounds to me like you're taking the wrong approach. The canvas should be no larger than the resolution of the screen then you should transform the canvas ([`scale`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/scale), [`translate`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/translate) etc.) so that it displays what you need. Likewise, make sure you aren't trying to render anything which won't actually be visible.

Comment: @MikeC I would have to draw the elements at the moment I pan a new part of the map into the viewport then? Are there any downsides (performance-wise) of drawing elements that are partly outside of the canvas, other than just the fact that I have to draw more?

Comment: Yes, you would have to draw elements which are only partly visible but it's definitely going to be faster than trying to draw the whole thing then shift the canvas around. The only "downside" is the one you mentioned: drawing more. But if those elements are at least partly visible, they need to be drawn so it's not so much of a downside as it is a requirement.

Comment: @MikeC This solutions seems inefficient in an other way to me. I would have to redraw very often (especially when zooming out). Thanks for the idea anyway. The current solutions works fine on desktop and iOS, the only issue is android.

Comment: I promise you that re-rendering is going to be faster than what you're doing. I've been doing this exact thing for a living for about 4 years now. Remember, you only have to re-render the minimal amount required for what's currently being displayed. You will want some kind of data structure in place to help you determine what exactly needs to be rendered so you don't waste CPU time on figuring it out every frame. The actual issue you're hitting is you're overloading the GPU so it has to fall back to software rendering.

Comment: @MikeC Oh boy, this is gonna be some work to do. Thanks for the input!

Comment: Sure thing. Good luck! If you have any specific issues with it, feel free to drop another question on SO. I check the [javascript] queue pretty often.

Comment: @MikeC If you put your suggestion that my approach is inefficient as an answer I will gladly accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The real problem you're hitting is you're overloading the GPU. Loading that much data all and once then moving it around is going to put a toll on the GPU and likely force the browser into software rendering mode, which is a big performance hit.

Instead, I'd suggest changing your approach. Rather than having various large canvases, you should have one canvas that is, at most, the size of the users screen. Then, utilize methods of the canvas API such as [`scale`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/scale) and [`translate`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/translate) to render what you need. For an added bonus, avoid trying to render things which are off screen.

It may seem like having to redraw the scene every time you move around would be slow but it's not. The reality is that either you specify *exactly* what needs to be drawn or the browser has to attempt to draw *all* of it again when you shift it around. Here's a brief example of how you can render and move large images.

```js
var ctx = document.querySelector('canvas').getContext('2d');
var img = new Image();
img.src = 'https://placeimg.com/1000/1000/nature';
img.onload = start;


function start() {
  var xDirection = -1;
  var yDirection = -1;
  var xPosition = 0;
  var yPosition = 0;
  
  var prev = Date.now();
  (function render() {
    var now = Date.now();
    var delta = (now - prev) / 1000;
    
    xPosition += xDirection * delta * 20;
    yPosition += yDirection * delta * 40;
    if (xPosition > 0) {
      xPosition = 0;
      xDirection *= -1;
    } else if (xPosition < -320) {
      xPosition = -320;
      xDirection *= -1;
    }
    if (yPosition > 0) {
      yPosition = 0;
      yDirection *= -1;
    } else if (yPosition < -240) {
      yPosition = -240;
      yDirection *= -1;
    }
    
    prev = now;
    ctx.save();
    ctx.translate(xPosition, yPosition);
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
    ctx.restore();
    requestAnimationFrame(render);
  })();
}
```

```css
body {
  background: #111;
}
canvas {
  background: #FFF;
}
```

```html
<canvas width="320" height="240"></canvas>
```

Comment: I would be happy if you could take a look at my follow up question here  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43543679/best-practice-for-zooming-and-panning-html5-canvas-with-10k-objects/