# Best practice for zooming and panning HTML5 canvas with > 10k objects

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas

I need to build kind of a map in canvas which displays over 10.000 elements (circles) and needs to be zoom- and panable. I described my approach here [Android significantly slower in resizing and moving multiple canvas elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43498805/android-significantly-slower-in-resizing-and-moving-multiple-canvas-elements?noredirect=1#comment74053025_43498805) and changed my implementation on suggestions made in the comments.

To pan the map `setTransform` is now used on the canvas context and then all elements that are in the viewport are redrawn after the canvas was erased. (I get them out of an R-Tree). This happens on every `mousemove` event.

While this is really fast when I have a zoomed map with ~200 objects to draw, the panning is really slow when zoomed out and over 10k objects need to be drawn. I obviously need it to be fast, too.

**What would be the best practice to fulfil this requirement?**
My approach would be the following:

- Have a viewport div over the canvas and make the canvas bigger (like 50% to each side)
- Move the canvas in the div with `top`and `left`styling and redraw less frequently (when the canvas gets close to the viewport border)

Comment: Do you have a lot of dynamic objects? As in, are there many objects moving in relation to other objects or is the content basically static?

Comment: @MikeC they won't move at all. I just might change the color of the circles depending on some ajax.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**My approach would probably be:**

- Create an on-screen canvas the size of the "viewport" (the size of the browser window for instance)
- Store the objects to draw in a data structure that lets you quickly determine which objects are visible at any given time (given the current viewport position and zoom).
- Make sure the objects to draw (circles) are available as bitmaps (either loaded from image file or pre-rendered to a canvas if you draw them with canvas).
- The circles's bitmap should be in the correct size given the zoom level, so pre-render the images to an off-screen canvas with the correct size when the zoom level changes. I'm assuming not all 10 000 points have unique images, that they all look the same or that there's only a handful variations.

**Then on each render:**

- Clear the canvas
- Call drawImage() for each circle being visible within the viewport, but only specify position, not width/height or use any transforms. The point being is that the image should only be "copied" to the viewport canvas 1-1. This is really fast.
- I would suggest to not redraw on every mousemove event (or window resize etc.). Instead, use window.requestAnimationFrame() to schedule a redraw. That way you're not redrawing more than the browser's "refresh" rate, typically 60fps.
- Panning in the viewport should be really fast since you're just calling drawImage() without any transformations for each visible circle. When you render and the zoom level has changed, there will be the cost of redrawing the pre-rendered images used as source for drawImage.

Comment: Thank you for the fast answer. I also read of "buffering" (is it called buffering?) meanwhile, sounds reasonable to me. Do I have to copy the pre drawn circles one by one or can I just take the visible part of my off-screen-canvas and set it as my viewport-canvas?
If not, should I make a canvas for each circle (I have max 10 different) or one for all (this is a sprite, isn't it?)

Comment: I agree that this is the approach to take. @Strernd If you draw it all to an off-screen canvas then you can treat that canvas as though it's an image. Basically, draw once to the buffer (assuming you have enough memory to draw the whole scene to the buffer and copy chunks of it) then you can do something like `drawImage(offScreenCanvas, srcX, srcY, srcWidth, srcHeight, dx, dy, dWidth, dHeight)`

Comment: If this turns out to be too memory intensive then you can consider drawing chunks of the scene at full scale as the user pans around. If you imagine you're drawing tiles and you're currently looking at the center, draw the center plus each tile in the 8 cardinal directions. Then when the user pans over a different tile, update your buffer to include *that* points surrounding tiles.

Comment: Thanks for helping me out

Comment: I came to the limit with this approach, since iPhone does not support canvas bigger than 4kx4k. @MikeC What is the advantage of using your approach with the chunks over just chunking the map in 4/9/16/.. parts?

Comment: @Strernd The advantage is that you don't need to have an incredibly large canvas while still giving you the added bonus of a quick buffer. If the user only moves around a little bit, you don't have to update your buffer and can render straight from the buffer to your main canvas. It also means that when the user does move outside of the current buffer zone, you can just take the existing buffer, translate it to match the users new area, draw the current buffer image to that position, then only render at most 1/3 of the new image. It's hard to explain in short comments but try it and you'll see

Comment: I guess I don't get the part with the translation. How could translate help me if I have to draw everything again after using translate? Do you have a resource showing what you mean with that?
I thought the way to do it is without transform?

Comment: Just to clarify: You don't need a canvas bigger than the viewport. Let's say the viewport is 800x600 pixels, then you create a canvas that size. This is the canvas you clear at the start of each render. If all circles look the same, you just need one more canvas: The canvas holding the bitmap data for the circle, which will be the source canvas for the drawImage() call that you do in the viewport for each visible circle. The area of the "map" can be virtually infinite. You would just need to scroll a lot :-)

Comment: @Strille I forgot to mention that I Could have around 200 individual  polygons on the map. Redrawing them at every frame or having to recalculate the sprites for them at every zoom seems inefficient. If you tell that this will be fast enough for 60fps, I'll try it.
I added a new question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43628923/canvas-drawimage-from-multiple-canvas-to-one-canvas-slow-in-chrome

Answer (score 5):

I second @Strilles answer.

here is a filtering example that switches between computing all sprites and computing visible-only sprites ever 5 seconds:

```js
var canvas = document.body.appendChild(document.createElement("canvas"));
canvas.width = 100;
canvas.height = canvas.width;
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(255,0,0,0.1)";
;
var sprites = [];
while (sprites.length < 100000) {
    sprites.push({
        x: Math.round(Math.random() * 10000 - 5000),
        y: Math.round(Math.random() * 10000 - 5000)
    });
}
var drawAll = true;
function draw() {
    var targets;
    if (drawAll == true) {
        targets = sprites.slice(0);
    }
    else {
        targets = sprites.filter(function (sprite) {
            return sprite.x > -10 && sprite.x < 110 && sprite.y > -10 && sprite.y < 110;
        });
    }
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    for (var t = 0; t < targets.length; t++) {
        var target = targets[t];
        ctx.fillRect(target.x - 5, target.y - 5, 10, 10);
        ctx.strokeRect(target.x - 5, target.y - 5, 10, 10);
    }
}
function main() {
    requestAnimationFrame(main);
    for (var i = 0; i < sprites.length; i++) {
        var sprite = sprites[i];
        sprite.y++;
        if (sprite.y > 110) {
            sprite.y -= 200;
        }
    }
    draw();
}
setInterval(function () {
    drawAll = !drawAll;
    console.log(drawAll ? "Draw all" : "Draw filtered");
}, 5000);
main();
```

Comment: Rendering only the actually visible objects sounds reasonable. I'm already doing this, by storing the objects in an R-tree and querying the viewport. Thanks for pointing out though.